# i need help to create grid\flex layout (CSS\SCSS)

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I have a problem too layout elements in a box on my website...

I want to build a 900x900px size box and put items in there, and when I reach the height limit of 900, then it will be split into two columns
attached picture to explain.

```css
.box {
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
}

.element {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="">
  <div class="element" id="">1</div>
  <div class="element" id="">2</div>
  <div class="element" id="">3</div>
  <div class="element" id="">4</div>
  <div class="element" id="">5</div>
  <div class="element" id="">6</div>
  <div class="element" id="">7</div>
  <div class="element" id="">8</div>
  ......
</div>
```

[image: example]

I tried playing with flexbox and grid but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score -1):

YOu can simply use a flexbox with a `flex-direction: column`. Then simply apply `flex-wrap: wrap` to it to allow it breaking into a next column. If you want to start at the right side you can use `direction: RTL` on the container.

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.element {
  height: 70px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="">
  <div class="element" id="">1</div>
  <div class="element" id="">2</div>
  <div class="element" id="">3</div>
  <div class="element" id="">4</div>
  <div class="element" id="">5</div>
  <div class="element" id="">6</div>
  <div class="element" id="">7</div>
  <div class="element" id="">8</div>
</div>
```